# How to sum vote values from a single field?

Tags: 7, views

I use a single field `Vote Results: Value` (with some relationships and contextual filters) which outputs the amount of votes every node has, in a list, like this:

- 5
- 3
- 4
- 2

However, I want it to look like this:

- 14

I tried to use the aggregation SUM on the field, but it didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing the sort criteria. Stupid mistake... :)